# javascript function not accessible from external file

Tags: javascript, jquery

This might be a stupid beginner's problem, but it's driving me mad. Simplified, the code is:

1. I have an index.php where in an inline script (located in the head element), some JS functions are defined.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){ 
       // other code
       var popup = function(message,color){
         $(".title").css({"color": "beige" });
         $(".popup_alert").css({"background-color": color});
         $( ".popup_alert" ).append(message);


         $(".popup_alert").removeClass("offscreen").delay(800).queue(function(){
           $(this).addClass("offscreen").dequeue();
           $(this).empty();
           $(".title").css({"color": "#444" });    
         });
       };
     };
   </script>
   ```
2. At the very bottom of the `<body>`, I'm loading an external JS file where some JQuery happens:

   ```
   <script src="ajaxToDB.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```

   JQuery is not the problem. It's loaded and the other functions inside this external file are working.
3. Inside this linked file, I can't call the function defined in the index.php.

   ```
   popup("test",orange);
   ```

   Will yield a console error "Uncaught ReferenceError: popup is not defined"

Is this normal? I already wrapped all the stuff in ajaxToDB.js inside a
$(function() {  ...  }); I read that this would force the page to load first, but to no avail...

What's the stupid detail I overlooked?!

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue at plnkr http://plnkr.co?

Comment: I'll try to....

Comment: I stripped it down to the bare minimum and it worked. http://plnkr.co/edit/CNCAXCzakI85z8NehbRV
However, I wasn't able to use PHP there. I'm now thinking it might be PHP related. This whole ajaxified mySQL access couldn't really be reproduced... :/

Comment: I saw that I had wrapped all inline <style> functions inside a main $(function(){};

When I added this in the minimalistic plnkr, it stopped working! Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @[guest271314](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2801559/guest271314), I learned a lesson in JS structure:

Previously, I had wrapped the entire code within the main document's script tag inside a `$(function(){};`  This I thought, was "necessary" as the script tag was placed inside the head element, and the document otherwise wouldn't have been ready.

When using another, external JS file however, this technique now prevented the external code from referring to functions declared inline, as these now "waited" for the rest of the document to be ready, including the external file (which then referred to a yet undeclared / "pending" main function).

Wow.

Removing the `$(function(){};` wrap and moving the script element to the bottom of the body resolved the issue. I guess that's where it should've been in the first place... **level up**

Comment: Variable scoping was also a problem. You declared `popup` inside the function definition, then tried to call it from outside the function.

Comment: This works because a script embedded in the HTML will always load before a script that's in another file that's referenced from the HTML. But if your application gets bigger, you'll probably need to use something like RequireJS to handle dependencies between modules.

Comment: Though the advice is correct, I'd suggest you to move your `popup` function to JS file and there you can write your `document.ready` function. Also, its better to define functions outside and then call them inside `document.ready`